# How to maintain the value in a variable and use it in another variable in another form

Tags: c#, windows, scope

I have two windows form. From form1 I connect to my server and as an output I get session id in a xml form. I parse the value and store it in a variable name session id. Now in form2 I need to use the session Id which I received in the previous form . How to do it? I was making the object of that class and using the data member but as the scope of the program gets over the value in the variable get removed.

Comment: You probably should have a model where you store common data instead of storing data in forms. This is a very basic software design question.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms) is your friend.. or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into static properties and (ultimately) static classes. Maybe not the most elegant solution but great learning material!

Edit: you can find a good tutorial here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/static

Comment: Not excatly but it was kind of useful help

Comment: Just made a proper use of static keyword. And work was done

Comment: Great! If you feel that my answer was right for you could you please click the accept mark?